# Repeated Music In VSE

Tags: animation, video-sequence-editor, audio

so i'm making an animation right? So then i'm working in VSE for a preview of what it looks like but when I play the preview animation with the music then the music just repeats as soon as a new scene is active. this happens even when I snap the strips in one channel. i'm new to VSE so I might not know some stuff.
here's a picture:[image]

Comment: Add a picture of your timeline..

Comment: Try taking your audio on the top, by clicking and draging!

Comment: still repeating

Comment: Have you heard your music out of Blender? Make sure your audio file is correct!

Comment: It’s only when the audio file reaches another scene strip, if there is only one scene strip then it runs without any repeated soundtrack

Comment: Okay...try taking your all SCENES strips on the same row.

Comment: It’s still repeating

Comment: I have one more solution

Answer (score 1):

I  figured it out, I had to set the volume of the second and third scene to 0.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is a right method!
You have three different animation scenes.
First scene is good to go, but second and third are not. So make them continuous to first.
 
I think I am messing up, but you must rename all frames of second and third scenes corresponding to first. For example, if your last frame of the first scene ends at frame 100(Blender names the file like 0100), then start renaming second scene frames from 101(0101) and after renaming second scenes frames check what is came in the last frame name(number) of second scene, then start renaming third scene frames where second scene frame ends, now COPY all the three scene's frames and paste them in a different common folder, now add all of them to VSE, there should have a single strip of animation. Add your audio file and try.

> I strongly recommend to **copy** after renaming, because **cutting**
>   may be risky.

Hope this helps.